# Is it worth to use NONCLUSTERD FILTERED INDEX with clause `<>''`?

Tags: nonclustered-index, filtered-index

I am just thinking to create `NONCLUSTERED FILTERED INDEX` with condition:

```
WHERE varcharColumn <> ''
```

This columns contains around 3127 different values including value `''`. All the queries has condition which are running on this table have condition:

```
WHERE varcharColumn <> ''
```

90% of rows contain the empty string, and would be excluded by this filter.

Do you think Is it worth co create such index with above clause ? Or maybe is better to create `NONCLUSTERED FILTERED INDEX` with clause:

```
WHERE varcharColumn = ''
```

Comment: Depends on the data distribution too - what are the row counts for the = and the <> cases?

Comment: Cases with = '' are 90%.

Comment: That 90% of rows would be excluded is a very valid piece of info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your queries mostly contain the `WHERE varcharColumn <> ''` condition then thats the one you need to use for the index - a filtered index does only contain references to the rows that match the condition so using `=` in the index definition would mean only rows with `''` can be found and it won't help your queries.

If the `varcharColumn <> ''` is only ~10% of the table then the index will be quite small and fast and very useful too.
If the ratio was reversed then the index would probably not help much and it would just take (more) space.

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe is better to create NONCLUSTERED FILTERED INDEX with clause: WHERE varcharColumn = ''

This would only exclude 10% of the data, at which point you are almost certainly better off with an unfiltered index which could be used for querying other values too.

> 90% of rows contain the empty string,

At 90% the filtered index isn't a lot of use even for queries where `varcharColumn = ''` is a predicate as you'll be scanning almost the full index anyway (unless some other index better serves the query in which case this index is not relevant).

> with condition: WHERE varcharColumn <> ''

Note that in most cases this will not significantly improve reading speeds compared to a full index¹. It could save a noticeable amount of space² though if the table contains a significant number of rows, which can reduce storage cost & index maintenance times and may improve insert/update performance a little for rows where that value is the empty string.

<sup>[1] it'll shave a page read or two off any action, and those reads would likely be from RAM so near instant</sup>

<sup>[2] approximately 90% of 4 bytes per row in the table assuming MS SQL Server and the clustering key³ is an integer, 16 bytes per row if the clustering key is a UUID, 8 bytes, the size of a RID value, per row if the table is a head (no clustering key)</sup>

<sup>[3] usually, but not always, the primary key</sup>